# Sanitize registration input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

This may be a really silly question but so far the interwebs has failed me, so i'm hoping you good people of SO will shed some light. Essentially I have a website on which there is membership functionality(sign up/login/forgotten password etc.) using the .net membership providers. Later down the line I am taking users registration data converting to XML then it using elsewhere in logic. Unfortunately I often get issues with the data I have in XML, more often than not its `hexadecimal value 0x1C, is an invalid character`. I did find a handy blog post on a resolution to this but it got me thinking, are there any standards on how data should be sanitized? What to let through registration and what not to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're (manually?) de-serializing the registration input, you need to [encode it as XML](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx) before further processing so that characters with special meaning in XML are escaped properly.

Note that there are only 5 of them so it's perfectly reasonable to do this with a manual replace:

- `<` = `&lt;`
- `>` = `&gt;`
- `&` = `&amp;`
- `"` = `&quot;`
- `'` = `&apos;`

You could use the build-in .NET function `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input)` to do this for you.

**UPDATE**:

I just realized I didn't really answer your question, you seem to be looking for a way to transform Unicode characters to ASCII-supported Html Entities.

I'm not aware of any built-in functions in .NET that do this, so I wrote a little utility method which should illustrate the concept:

```
public static class StringUtilities
{
    public static string HtmlEncode(string input, Encoding source, Encoding destination)
    {
        var sourceChars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input).ToArray();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var sourceChar in sourceChars)
        {
            byte[] sourceBytes = source.GetBytes(new[] { sourceChar });
            char destChar = destination.GetChars(sourceBytes).FirstOrDefault();

            if (destChar != sourceChar)
                sb.AppendFormat("&#{0};", (int)sourceChar);
            else
                sb.Append(sourceChar);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then, given an input string which has both reserved XML characters and Unicode characters in it, you could use it like this:

```
string unicode = "<tag>some proӸematic text<tag>";

string escapedASCII = StringUtilities.HtmlEncode(
    unicode, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII);

// Result: &lt;tag&gt;some pro&#1272;ematic text&lt;tag&gt;
```

If you need to do this at several places, to clean it up a bit, you could add an extension method for your specific scenario:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToEncodedASCII(this string input, Encoding sourceEncoding)
    {
        return StringUtilities.HtmlEncode(input, sourceEncoding, Encoding.ASCII);
    }
    public static string ToEncodedASCII(this string input)
    {
        return StringUtilities.HtmlEncode(input, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII);
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
string unicode = "<tag>some proӸematic text<tag>";

// Default to Unicode as input
string escapedASCII1 = unicode.ToEncodedASCII();

// Pass in a different encoding for your input
string escapedASCII2 = unicode.ToEncodedASCII(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);
```

**UPDATE #2**

Since you also asked for advice on adhering to standards, the most I can tell you is that you need to take into consideration where the input text will actually end up.

If the input for a certain user will only ever be displayed to that user (for instance when they manage their profile / account settings in your app), and your database supports Unicode, you could just leave everything as-is.

On the other hand, if the information can be displayed to other users (for instance when users can view each others public profile information) then you need to take into consideration that not all users will be visiting your website on a device/browser that supports Unicode. In that case, UTF-8 is likely to be your best bet.

This is also why you can't really find that much useful information on it. If the world was able to agree on a standard then we would not have to deal with all these encoding variations in the first place. Think about your target group and what they need.

A useful blog post on the subject of encoding: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question isn't so much about parsing xml, its more about the standards of what should be parsed and how in respect to Registration Data e.g. email, first name, last name. Sorry if this wasn't clear in the question

Comment: I just updated my answer with how to encode Unicode for compatibility in ASCII, not sure if this answers your question either now that I read your comment, though. Could you provide an example of registration data you're getting and what exactly goes wrong with it?

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for my issue specifically, but I was just wondering if there was a standard for parsing any data, what the standardized route is to take, but thank you anyway for a nicely detailed answer

Comment: Please see my UPDATE #2, perhaps that's the information you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful, you clearly spent a good amount of time on your answer and i am very grateful!